# Javascript regular expression only accept specific characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate a field when a form is submitted, but only specific characters are allowed. Those characters are:

```
a-z A-Z 0-9 % . " ' & - @ # $ * / + = [ ] !
```

I thought the following regex would work:

```js
var regex = new RegExp(/[a-zA-Z0-9%\. "'&@#\$\*\/\+=\[\]\!-]+/);
```

I tested it out https://regexr.com/4kigt, and it seems to match the pattern. However, when I attempt to validate on form submit, it doesn't fail when characters like `(`, `)`, or `?` are entered. For example, when I enter `(afasdf)` into the form field, the match is `true`.

Any idea how to to fix this?

```html
<input type="text" class="field">
<p>
    <button>Validate</button>
</p>
```

```js
var field = document.querySelector('.field');
var button = document.querySelector('button');
var regex = new RegExp(/[a-zA-Z0-9%\. "'&@#\$\*\/\+=\[\]\!-]+/, 'g');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(regex.test(field.value));
}, false);
```

Jsbin link https://jsbin.com/forupos/edit?html,js,console,output.

Comment: When you use regex constructor, you must not use delimiters `var regex = new RegExp('[a-zA-Z0-9%\. "'&@#\$\*\/\+=\[\]\!-]+', 'g');`  or use `var regex = /[a-zA-Z0-9%\. "'&@#\$\*\/\+=\[\]\!-]+/g;`

Comment: Does not check the entire string, it is just says a portion of the string matches that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns `true` for `(afasdf)`, but it actually matches `afasdf`. You should use `^n` and `n$` anchors.

```
var regex = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9%\. "'&@#\$\*\/\+=\[\]\!-]+$/);
```

Comment: I think the correct term here is "anchors" rather than "quantifiers", but yes--without `^` (beginning of line) and `$` (end of line) anchors, partial string matches are permitted by the original regex.

Comment: Still doesn't work. If I enter something like `(abd23.- );:`, the test returns true even though `();:` aren't permitted characters.

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9%\. "'&@#\$\*\/\+=\[\]\!-]+$/.test( "(abd23.- );:" )` does not evaluate to `true`.